# Error Tokenizing Data

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file from a collaborator.  He told me I could read it into into python using

```
import csv

t = []
f = open("measles.csv", "rb")
d = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"', delimiter="\t", lineterminator='\r\n')
for row in d:

    t.append(row)
```

I tried to make a dataframe out of the data by using `pd.DataFrame(t[1:],colums = t[0])` which was successful.  However, when I write the resulting dataframe to csv, and then try to read it back in again using `pd.read_csv`, I get the following error

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

I suspect it is to do with the way the data was originally given to me.  I've tried `error_bad_lines = False` but that doesn't seem to work.  Any advice?

Comment: I'm surprised you open the CSV file in binary mode. You could see if using plain text mode makes a difference.

Comment: @Evert In Python 2.x CSV files should be opened in binary mode: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: @Evert reading in plain text mode doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: can we have a file sample ?

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO Found here http://salathegroup-static.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/crowdbreaks/measles-crowdbreaks-20150601-20151231.tar.gz

Comment: there is chinesse in it ...and incorrect chars, in fact it's not a csv file

Comment: @LonGdueZBOO You think that is the problem?  Anyway I could get around it?

Comment: i think there an endless line wich cause overflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104972/discussion-between-demetri-p-and-longduezboo).

Comment: It looks like some one open the csv in excel and save as it.

Comment: FWIW it's working here with your sample file.

Comment: sorry, i read better in text file, it's not a csv but it a tab separate well formed csv like.( text beetween "")

Comment: i've done some research, wich version of python do you use ?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: work also on python 2.7.11

Comment: work on windows 10 with python 2.7...

Answer (score 0):

With 
pd.read_csv try `engine='python'` parameter.

ex.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name , engine='python')
```